# using curl to login into a website

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am using a `php` code to login into a website ,
I am using curl to do that, but I have a problem :( to login into specific website... when I use this code, it don't login (that means if I post a wrong password or a wrong username it don't show me the login error I think it doesn't post my data ?!?!?!?! I don't know, please see the code blow)

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://example.com/login.php';
$data = "css/style1.css";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=something&password=something");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
$answer = str_replace('href="','href="'.$url.'/',$answer);
echo $answer;
?>
```

I should say I use this code on another website url but it works and it shows me the error login but in this web site it don't work....

here is the my url html source to login(login page):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>my url code</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_outer">
</div>
  <form method="post" action="" class="login">
    <p>
      <label for="login">Username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="password">Password: </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="">
    </p>

    <p class="login-submit">
      <button type="submit" name="Login" class="login-button">Login</button>
    </p>
    <p class="forgot-password"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot your password?</a></p>
  
   
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` for debugging. (No, nobody here can tell you what's wrong without a concrete error message, or knowing how the example site handles logons [or blocks scripted access] really. The double `/index.php` may be relevant though. And the lack of submit button request value perhaps.)

Comment: in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` the **p** of `password` is missing

Comment: dear mario CURLOPT_VERBOSE is undefined constant

Comment: Use of undefined constant CURL_VERBOSE

Comment: i use curl_errno($ch) and return 0 .....???!!!! it have no error but it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: If you use the  element in an HTML form, different
>   browsers may submit different values.
>   From 
>   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

That means the button is being submitted too, with a parameter of its name "Login", so you have to include it in your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS so it will be processed.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=something&password=something&Login=true");
```